# HTMLPurifier label tag support

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I can't make `<label>` tag recognizable by HTMLPurifier.

Running

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'label');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
echo $purifier->purify("<label>Link</label>");
```

Throws `Warning: Element 'label' is not supported (for information on implementing this, see the support forums)`.

Also no luck using addElement()

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'test');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);
if ($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition()) {
   $def->addElement('label', 'Block', 'Inline', 'Common', array());
}
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
echo $purifier->purify("<label>Link</label>");
```

Still returns just `Link`, where I expect `<label>Link</label>`. Any thoughts?

**Update**: Using `$config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);` does the difference, but it disables XSS protection. Not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

After changing configuration, you need to make sure to clean cache in `vendor/ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier/DefinitionCache/Serializer/` or temporary disable caching using

```
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null);
```

If you use `$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'h1,h2,...');` you also need to add `label` there.